# Why is the axiom of pairing not stated simply as "for any set $x$, there exists a set $Y$ such that $x\in Y$"?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

Wouldn't it be easier to just say that for any set $x$, there exists a set $Y$ such that $x\in Y$? That seems like a simpler statement. Plus for any sets $x, y$, this statement + restricted comprehension gives the sets {$x$}, {$y$}. So union would give us {$x, y$} and we recover the original axiom of pairing.

I have not taken a set theory course.

Comment: Notice that the [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) doesn't work for your last step. In order to apply that axiom, you'd still need to "pair up" the sets $\{x\},\{y\}$ to form $S=\{\{x\},\{y\}\}$ before taking $\bigcup S$.

Comment: ohhhhh that clears things up